# Error: { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, server-side-rendering

After searching a lot I'm still not able to fix this error in my SSR angular project:

> Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000 ERROR Something
>   went wrong please try again later! ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'fontawesome-webfont.woff2' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2'
>
> __zone_symbol__value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2'

And a lot more of error like above:

[As per discussion here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1463) I've tried a lot of changes to my font-awesome import but not successful in removing the error.

I've tried changing

```
$fa-font-path: "../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

To

```
$fa-font-path: "../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

And

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

As well but same error persists.
My configuration is same as [this project](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)